# IF statements based on numerical value(1,0) in table to determine string result

Tags: mysql, sql

In the query I am fetching values from two tables `company` and `person`. I using  an if statement inside the query to determine if a person is a `student` or a `teacher`. The values are stored in the db table as `1` and `0` under `teacher_status` and `student_status`. I have read prior to asking this question some documentation about `mysql if statements` and found some useful examples but I can’t get to display the correct results with the scenario mention above. How can I display with `YES` or `NO` that a person is a student, teacher or both? [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/79a03/2)

```
SELECT a.id, a.company_id,  p.teacher_status AS teacher, p.student_status AS student
FROM company a
LEFT JOIN person p
ON a.company_id = p.company_id
IF p.teacher_status = 1 THEN SET p.teacher_status = 'YES'
ELSE SET p.teacher_status = 'NO'
IF p.student_status = 1 THEN SET p.student_status = 'YES'
ELSE SET p.teacher_status = 'NO'
```

Tables Structure:

```
CREATE TABLE company
(
  id int auto_increment primary key,
  company_id int,
  name varchar(20)
);
CREATE TABLE person
(
 id int auto_increment primary key,
employee_id int,
 company_id int,
 person_name varchar(20),
 teacher_status int,
 student_status int
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this with `CASE`

```
SELECT a.id, a.company_id, 
(CASE WHEN p.teacher_status = '1' THEN  'YES' ELSE 'NO' END
) AS teacher,
(CASE WHEN p.student_status = 1 THEN  'YES' ELSE 'NO' END
) AS student,
p.teacher_status, /* for testing purpose only to view the field value */
p.student_status  /* for testing purpose only to view the field value */
FROM company a
LEFT JOIN person p
ON a.company_id = p.company_id
```

[**See Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d34de/1)

Answer (score 0):

Using `IF` you can try this:

```
SELECT a.id, a.company_id,  
IF(p.teacher_status = 1, 'YES', 'NO') AS teacher,
IF(p.student_status = 1, 'YES', 'NO') AS student
FROM company a
LEFT JOIN person p
ON a.company_id = p.company_id
```

Working Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d34de/4